# Android Jsoup get the full version of the site

Tags: android, jsoup

Loading page

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
```

The site has two versions, standard and mobile, how to get the full version, not mobile?

Comment: Off the cuff, see if JSoup has options for you to set the `User-agent` header, and then set it to something that advertises itself as a desktop browser. Or, download the HTML using some other HTTP API that does offer to let you set headers, then process the results with JSoup.

Comment: I tried it   `String userAgent = System.getProperty("http.agent"); Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).referrer("http://www.google.com").userAgent(userAgent).get();`  but to no avail

Comment: That would specifically give you a mobile edition of the site, as the system-level user-agent string would be for mobile.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand how I solved my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution

```
 Document document = Jsoup.connect(url)
                    .referrer("http://www.google.com")
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US;   rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6").get();
```